# Range.Find type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my code:

Need my code to enter TRUE in a cell if it finds a value in column A of sheet "Itemschedule" to be present in column B of sheet "Whereused". Getting "Type mismatch" error. If I change the "st = Sheets(..." line to .Value instead of .Text, or if I change the .Find line to LookIn:=xlFormulas instead of Lookin:=xlValues, it gives the same error irrespective of the combination of the two.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowLast As Integer
Dim str As String
Dim cell As Range

Sheets("Itemschedule").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter
rowLast = Sheets("Itemschedule").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Itemschedule").ListObjects("Table2").Resize Range("A1:E" & rowLast)
Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("A" & rowLast + 1 & ":E" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
For i = 2 To rowLast
    str = Sheets("Itemschedule").Cells(i, "A").Text
    With Sheets("Whereused").Range("B:B")
        Set cell = .Find(What:=str, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Itemschedule").Cells(i, "E").Value = "FALSE"
    Else
        Sheets("Itemschedule").Cells(i, "E").Value = "TRUE"
    End If
Next
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Itemschedule").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter
Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("A1:E" & rowLast).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("A1:E" & rowLast).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Sheets("Itemschedule").ListObjects("Table2").Resize Range("A1:E" & rowLast)
Sheets("Itemschedule").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

I have tried a lot but am not able to figure it out. I'm sure it's something silly.
Please help.

Comment: try to debug.print a `TypeName(.Find(What:=str, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False))`, hope it may give an idea of what type of object is being churned out... possibly an error, just guessing

Comment: Why not `Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("E2:E" & rowLast).Formula = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, Whereused!B:B, 0)"` then `Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("E2:E" & rowLast) = Sheets("Itemschedule").Range("E2:E" & rowLast).Value`?

Comment: @Jeeped, I like your method, it looks simple. But the formula line is giving an "Application defined or object defined error" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to the fact that the After parameter is not inside the range you are searching. This part:

```
With Sheets("Whereused").Range("B:B")
        Set cell = .Find(What:=str, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
```

should be:

```
With Sheets("Whereused").Range("B:B")
        Set cell = .Find(What:=str, After:=Sheets("Whereused").Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
```

otherwise the `.Range("B1")` is relative to `Range("B:B")` and therefore refers to C1.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are more efficient at finding duplicate values.

```js
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim keyword As String, keyvalue As Variant
    Dim rowLast As Long, x As Long
    Dim dicItems
    Set dicItems = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    With Sheets("Whereused")
        rowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To rowLast
            keyword = .Cells(x, 2)
            keyvalue = .Cells(x, 2)
            'Add Key Value pairs to Dictionary
            If Not dicItems.Exists(keyword) Then dicItems.Add keyword, keyvalue
        Next
    End With

    With Sheets("Itemschedule")
        rowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To rowLast
            keyword = .Cells(x, 1)
            .Cells(x, 2) = dicItems.Exists(keyword)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

But the proper way to do it place a WorkSheet Formula in Itemschedule Column B.

> =COUNTIF(Table1[[#This Row],[Items]],Table2[[#Headers],[Items]])>0